# Nuxt: how to display a top level component inside of multiple routed pages without reloading it?

Tags: vue.js, components, nuxt.js

I started a new job and I need to build a website with nuxt. A typical website would look like this in a nuxt layout file:

```
<NavMenu />
<Nuxt /> - my different routed pages
<Footer />
```

Whenever I change a page `<Nuxt />` displays another page, but `<NavMenu />` stays as is.

But the website I am building now needs a particular design. Imagine each page looking like this:
(NB: this is purely a design/layout description, not actual vue components)

```
<HeroImage /> - different for each page, belongs to that specific page
<NavMenu /> - always the same, belongs to the general layout
<MyPageContent /> - content belongs to specific page
```

The hero image is almost full screen. If you're wondering why the `<NavMenu />` is tucked after a fullscreen hero image, it is because when you scroll, the NavMenu is scrolled into view, and whenever it reaches the top of the page, it stays sticky. Here's an example of such sticky navbar: https://codepen.io/bencasalino/pen/MOLQKM

I want to display the NavMenu after the HeroImage. My problem is figuring out how to display a top level component inside of multiple routed pages without reloading it. I can't put the NavMenu inside of individual pages, because if I change the page, that would destroy it and create a brand new NavMenu every time. Also, I can't put HeroImage outside of the `<Nuxt />` component because it belongs to its own specific page (the image is different for every page).
I thought I could solve this problem with `<teleport>`, which allows to move an element to another position in the DOM with a css selector. I would have done something like this:

```
<teleport to="somewhere_after_the_hero_image" >
    <NavMenu />
</teleport>
<Nuxt /> - my different pages
<Footer />

// Pages would look like this
<HeroImage />
<div class="somewhere_after_the_hero_image"></div>
<PageContent />
```

The problem is that Nuxt doesn't allow it yet because it runs on Vue 2, and `<teleport>` is a recent feature from Vue3. What would be the most logical way to create this layout?  Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you try the `layout` in `nuxt`?

Comment: Maybe you could create a custom layout in the `layouts` folder and get the current route by accessing `this.$route`. Then , in this custom layout you would have your `<NavMenu />` and the `<HeroImage />`, but the <HeroImage /> would be dynamic according to the route (you could pass a param to the Hero Image, according to the `this.$route`).

Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the perfect answer, but one way of doing it might be using the vue store to pass (img url) data from the page created in `<Nuxt />` to my HeroImage component.
In the end, I took another approach: my HeroImage is created inside of the Nuxt component, below the menu, and then I used Javascript to put everything into place.